# Mysql row into array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This question has already been asked tons of times, but I can't really understand how to do this.

I'm trying to insert the values of an entire row, into an array in PHP. 
Here is the query result:

```
+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
+ Ln1 + Ln2 + Mar1 + Mar2 + Mar3 + Mer1 + Mer2 + Mer3+
+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
+  1  +  1  +   1  +  1   +  1   +  1   +  1   +  1  +
+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
```

I would like to insert all those '1' into an array called `$giorni`, actually I'm using

```
$arr_prep= array("Ln1","Ln2","Mar1","Mar2","Mar3","Mer1","Mer2","Mer3");
$giorni = array();

    for($c = 0; $c < 8; $c++){

        $temp = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT '$arr_prep[$c]' FROM Corsi WHERE id='$id'"));
        array_push($giorni,$temp);

    }
```

And the result printed with `"echo "giorni -->".array_values($giorni);"` is:

```
giorni -->Arraygiorni -->Arraygiorni -->Arraygiorni -->Arraygiorni -->Arraygiorni -->Arraygiorni -->Arraygiorni -->Array
```

I've also tried with `mysql_fetch_array` and `mysql_fetch_row`, maybe I'm using them in the wrong way but I could not make it work.
Can anyone suggest me how to do it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Code Example]

```
Try Changing SELECT '$arr_prep[$c]' FROM... to SELECT $arr_prep[$c] FROM..
```

Remove ''

you'll get output as 
Array ( [0] => 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv5QA.jpg) => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 )

Comment: Thanks! But now, how to i parse it? I mean, i want to call $giorni[x] and get "1".

Comment: All i needed was a typecasting --> array_push($giorni,(int)$temp);